# Which models / techniques could help me accelerate my child's intellectual development?

Tags: development, cognitive-development, play

this is my first question here, thanks for having me :)
Apologies if this question seems to be a little bit subjective, let me try and more clearly define what I'm asking.

My first child (daughter) is due March 2019. Like all parents I want to ensure I'm doing everything I can to create an environment wherein she can psychologically and intellectually (and physically in terms of motor function) flourish to the maximum of her ability. My issue is, I know very little about developmental psychology and even less about pedagogy.

Particularly in reference to early years (but right up to UK secondary school age would be interesting to hear about), **what are the popular models, frameworks or techniques that I should be reading about and trying to put into practice as a parent?**

I am a fast reader and can handle in-depth explanations, but I'm aware that there is no *absolute* best way of doing things. I've read a LITTLE about John Piaget's work, which has led me to believe I should try and provide play activities that will encourage my daughter to investigate the properties of a range of objects and materials, but I guess I'm looking for guidance on any other leading theories with some practical advice on application.

I don't want to just keep buying meaningless 'toys' for my daughter, I want to know I'm doing my best to keep her ahead of (or at least not behind) the developmental curve. Obviously, I also realize that having general fun is part of being a child but I guess I want to make sure that fun is playing a part in her development as far as possible.

What should I be reading?

Thank you all so much and I look forward to your input.

Comment: I don't know if there is a proper way to "link" related questions, but you might find some good info here. I like how your question is more focused on methods of educational play.  https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/35372/formal-curriculum-for-infants-first-few-years

Comment: Thank you to the community, I must admit it seems odd yet understandable that I can't respond to user ELBRANT as I lack the rep to comment on his/her reply. In case it helps any other potential parent, I've been stupid asking about frameworks as many have been superceded, but I recommend reading on Piaget in practice, structured play examples, free play, early years spontaneous activity planning. Once again apologies for subjective question, gutted about down votes but understood. I look forward to posting more specific questions, happy holidays where appropriate!! X

Answer (score 2):

I applaud your intentions of helping her to learn as much as she can. Take a look at the [Parenting for Brain](https://www.parentingforbrain.com/) website. It seems like it would fit in with your goals. Children will excell naturally when presented with posiitve life experiences, good teachers, safe environments, and so on.   But, please, be careful. Parents often, unwittingly, put too much emphasis on being better than other children. Don't focus on the other kids, only on your daughter and her natural talents and abilities.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm a believer in only competing with yourself, you set your own standards and goals I agree. Your link was helpful so thanks. I know children can't be PROGRAMMED I just want some insight into the concepts they should understand at what age so I can judge progress and identify strengths and weaknesses in my daughter X bless you